# Performance: should I use a global variable in a function which gets called often?

Tags: c++, c, performance, embedded, global-variables

First off, let me get of my chest the fact that I'm a greenhorn trying to do things the right way which means I get into a contradiction about what is the right way every now and then.

I am modifying a driver for a peripheral which contains a function - lets call it `Send()`. In the function I have a timestamp variable so the function loops for a specified amount of time.

So, should I declare the variable global (that way it is always in memory and no time is lost for declaring it each time the function runs) or do I leave the variable local to the function context (and avoid a bad design pattern with global variables)?

Please bear in mind that the function can be called multiple times per milisecond.

Comment: Declarations of variables is something that happens during compilation only, not during run-time.

Comment: So declaring the variable locally won't affect execution time?

Comment: Measure, don't guess. But, assuming it's a simple type, a local variable should cost little or nothing, and may be faster to access than a global.

Comment: Besides measuring, you could always compare the generated assembly code for the two ways.

Comment: Can you describe how you intend to use this mystery timestamp variable in `Send()`? Understanding the context will make it easier to suggest a solution

Comment: Nasser, `Send()` will try to fill the transmit buffer of a controller for 2ms in case it is full at the time being.

Comment: I completely disagree, depends on the code, local variables can and do greatly affect performance.  There is a performance cliff you fall off using local variables, so long as it doesnt actually have to use the stack you get performance similar or slightly better than globals, but as you add each line of code or operation to that function you will approach and fall off the performance cliff dues to the local variables.

Comment: A local variable which can be held in a register would seem fastest.  One referenced relative to the stack pointer next, at least if the processor can do a small-offset-relative address in fewer instructions than an arbitrary address one as is likely needed for a global variable.  As soon as you have *any* local stack variables, it shouldn't matter what moderate number of them you have, until you hit a limit for relative addressing or cross a caching boundary.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952670/do-global-variables-mean-faster-code/3952997

Comment: ... and [A Pox On Globals](http://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/break-points/4025723/A-pox-on-globals)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Speed of execution shouldn't be significantly different for a local vs. a global variable. The only real difference is where the variable lives. Local variables are allocated on the stack, global variables are in a different memory segment. It is true that local variables are allocated every time you enter a routine, but allocating memory is a single instruction to move the stack pointer.

There are much more important considerations when deciding if a variable should be global or local.

Comment: Excellent. Obviously I had ill knowledge about variable allocation speed.

Comment: *Local* and *stack allocation* are not synonymous - local variables declared `static` have identical storage class to globals and variables with static linkage (i.e. file scope).  C++ additionally has namespace and class scopes - no variable ever need be global.

Comment: @Clifford You are correct about static local and static linkage variables. My answer was intentionally limited in it's detail. I was just trying to make it clear that speed of execution was not a reason to avoid local variables.

Comment: what are the "much more important considerations" please?

Answer (score 5):

**When implementing a driver, try to avoid global variables as much as possible, because:**

1. They are thread-unsafe, and you have no idea about the scheduling scheme of the user application (in fact, even without threads, using multiple instances of the same driver is a potential problem).
2. It automatically yields the creation of data-section as part of the executable image of any application that links to your driver (which is something that the application programmer might want to avoid).

Answer (score 2):

Did you profile a fully-optimized, release build of your code and identify the bottleneck to be small allocations in this function?

The change you are proposing is a micro-optimization; a change to a small part of your code with the intent to make it more efficient.  If the question to the above question is "no" as I'd expect, you shouldn't even be thinking of such things.

Select the correct algorithm for your code.  Write your code using idiomatic techniques.  Do not write in micro-optimizations.  You might be surprised how good your compiler is at optimizing your code for you.  It will often be able to optimize away these small allocations, but even if it can't you still don't know if the performance penalty imposed by them is even noticeable or significant.

Comment: No, I did not profile the application (but will ASAP). Thanks for your suggestion about micro-optimizations, will keep in mind!

Comment: this doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 0):

For drivers, with is usually position independent, global variables are accessed indirectly with GOT table unless IP-relative operations is available (i.e. x86_64, ARM, etc)

In case of GOT, you can think it as an extra indirect pointer.

However, even with an extra pointer it won't make any observable difference if it's "only" called in mill-second frequency.